# How create two supersets from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

these are my tables.

```
Main
------
mainid(PK)     
1           
2                    
3           


Emp
-----
empid(PK)    Name      
1            Dave            
2            Dan            
3            Mark            
4            Steve     
5            Elvis
6            Jacob

Tools
-----
toolid(PK)         
1                       
2                        
3                        
4                 
5            
6            


MainEmp
-----
mainid(FK)   empid(FK)      
1            1            
1            2            
2            3            
2            4            
3            5
3            6

MainTools
-----
mainid(FK)   tools(FK)      
1            1            
1            2            
1            3            
2            4            
3            5
3            6
```

I want to achieve this query result

```
mainid       emp            tools     
1            Dave, Dan       1,2,3     
2            Mark, Steve     4            
3            Elvis,Jacob     5,6
```

I'm using following sql

```
 select m.mainid,
 listagg(emp.name, ',') within group (order by emp.empid)
 from main m join
 mainemp me
 on m.mainid = me.mainid join
 emp e
 on e.empid = me.empid
 group by m.mainid
```

It does work if I try to display main with emp or main with tools. However I can't figure it out how to connect it together. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the aggregations in subqueries, and then join them together:

```
select m.*, n.names, mt.tools
from main m left outer join
     (select me.mainid, listagg(e.name, ',') within group (order by e.name) as names
      from MainEmp me join
           Employees e
           on e.empid = me.empid
      group by me.mainid
     ) n
     on m.mainid = n.mainid
     (select mt.mainid, listagg(mt.tools, ',') within group (order by mt.tools) as tools
      from MainTools mt
      group by mt.mainid
     ) mt
     on m.mainid = mt.mainid
```

Comment: by `mt.tools` you mean `mt.toolid` ?

Comment: @Rezus . . . In the `MainTable` in the question, the column has the name `tools`.  `ToolId` would make more sense for the column name.

Comment: Right, but when I execute the sql I get this `ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 65`. Do I need to add order by in the first listagg sentence?

Comment: @Rezus . . . Yes, I think it does need the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

If is oracle 11g,you can also do like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MAINID,
WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY A.MAINID) AS NAMES,
WM_CONCAT(DISTINCT D.TOOLS) OVER(PARTITION BY A.MAINID ) AS TOOLS
FROM 
MAIN A JOIN MAINEMP B
ON A.MAINID=B.MAINID
JOIN EMP C
ON B.EMPID=C.EMPID
JOIN MAINTOOLS D
ON A.MAINID=D.MAINID
```